# Python3 - Check a list against a CSV file, and return every item in the CSV file that is not in the list

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of hostnames, ie `['AEDUZ842', 'AEDBKR392, 'AEDUB492'] ETC..` which I am trying to check against a CSV file also containing hostnames. The end goal is to return every item which exists in the CSV file, but not in the list - in order to verify which hosts DO NOT exist in my environment. Truth be told I have made no progress figuring this out, and could really really use some help.

Sample CSV:
`WAMJxxxFH893,AEDxxx023,AExxx023,AEDUxxx24,AEDxxx25,AEDxxx026`

Comment: So are the `xxx`s in the csv-file strings placeholders that stand for any combination of 3 characters?

Answer (score 0):

** Update with OP's updated list

input example:

```py
csv_list = ["WAMJxxxFH893", "AEDxxx023", "AExxx023", "AEDUxxx24", "AEDxxx25", "AEDxxx026"]
host_list = ["WAMJxxxFH893", "AEDUxxx24", "AEDxxx026"]
[item for item in csv_list if item not in host_list]
```

output:

```py
['AEDxxx023', 'AExxx023', 'AEDxxx25']
```

This will return all the items in your csv list that are not in your other list.

Comment: I implemented this solution, but the output is every item in the CSV file- not just the items exclusive to said CSV file. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: The above looks for exact matches then returns strings that are not exact matches. So if the string you use for your host names in your host list is not the same format as the string you use for the host name in the CSV file, it will just return all the items in the CSV file. e.g. if your host list name is "AEDUZ842" but is represented in the CSV file as "AEDUZxxx842" then those host names are not the same.